# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: bash, software-installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install geda
```

After that I'm supposed to

- Run gnetlist once to generate the required system folders

  ```
  gnetlist --help 1>/dev/null 2>./gEDA Install errors.log
  ```
- Create a directoy called gaf. This directory is where all gEDA projects should be stored. Each project should prefereably
  have its own directory.

  ```
  mkdir  ̃/gaf 2>./gEDA Install errors.log
  ```
- Create a directory that will contain all the custom symbols:

  ```
  mkdir  ̃/gaf/symbols 2>./gEDA Install errors.log
  ```
- The following command may be executed on the terminal from the users home once in order to set the path to symbols folders for all gEDA projects to use:

  ```
  echo “ (component-library-search \“${HOME}/gaf/symbols/\”) ”  ̃/.gEDA/gafrc
  ```

The last command returned

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

what is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: what software are you installing and how? Your question is very unclear! Please give complete commands used and complete output

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely the Unicode quote marks: change them to regular ASCII quotes:

```
$ echo “ (component-library-search \“${HOME}/gaf/symbols/\”) ”
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

whereas

```
$ echo " (component-library-search \"${HOME}/gaf/symbols/\") "
 (component-library-search "/home/steeldriver/gaf/symbols/")
```

Comment: `̃/` is most likely wrong too and meant to be `~/`.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem has to do with your quoting. You can solve it by changing the line to

```
echo '(component-library-search \“${HOME}/gaf/symbols/\”)' >  ̃/.gEDA/gafrc
```

Why? " are weak quotings. The 2. " is ending the quote and that is resulting in a syntax error. Also if there wasn't the 2., the variable would still be parsed because there are only weak quotings.

' are strong quotings. " and $ inside are not going to be parsed and that's why there is no syntax error resulting.